# ./node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles/index.js:1:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

After updating Angular from v12 to v14 started getting following issues

```
./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-CYVTLM4Z.js:5:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-E7NQQTT7.js:3:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-TOKOIIBI.js:5:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-TOKOIIBI.js:514:48-61 - Error: export 'fileURLToPath' (imported as 'fileURLToPath') was not found in 'url' (possible exports: Url, format, parse, resolve, resolveObject)

./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-XYNRD7NE.js:2:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/private/localize.js:1:0-6tible/srnpack-angular/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/private'

./node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles/chunk-B2TZRIF5.js:6:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles/chunk-HN4VPUZT.js:8:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles/chunk-N3C6NOYD.js:9:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles'

./node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles/index.js:1:0-61 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '/home/user/Desktop/angular/node_modules/@angular/localize/tools/bundles'


{
[tag:  "name": "srnpack",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -c dev --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --ssl --ssl-key --ssl-cert",
    "serve-local": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy-local.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production --output-hashing=all",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc:build": "compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json",
    "compodoc:build-and-serve": "compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json -s",
    "compodoc:serve": "compodoc -s"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^14.0.0-beta.41",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw": "^7.0.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-markercluster": "^5.0.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.5",
    "@busacca/ng-pick-datetime": "12.0.0",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "~10.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@types/quill": "^1.3.10",
    "angular-file-saver": "1.1.3",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.18.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "flag-icon-css": "^4.1.6",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^5.0.0",
    "ng-qrcode": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^3.1.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.6",
    "ngx-chips": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^2.5.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-moment": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "ngx-quill": "^17.1.1",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "postcode-validator": "^3.2.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.3.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.21",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.7",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }}]
```

I've tried deleting node modules and npm cache clean